# How to get a certain part of current URL in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need a certain part of current URL. 
Say for example the URL is: http://www.abc.com/123/product/234?productid=123 
And I want to check if a certain string contains http://www.abc.com/123

Please don't give answers like "do string manipulation" and all. 
Is there a way to get this sort of URL?

Comment: Please be more specific if my answer is not correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class has some really helpful methods for Uri mangling - including Uri.TryCreate.

Specifically, the [GetComponents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents.aspx) method might help you.

Comment: Good information but couldn't found something in this which can help me.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri
```

That will give the url to your .xap file.
You will have to replace your .xap path and you have your application uri.

```
Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri.Replace(@"ClientBin/MySilverlight.xap", "");
```

Comment: You can unhardcode that string as well.. replace it with the `Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsolutePath` value...

Answer (score 2):

I opted for a completely generic solution:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the site URL (one step up from ClientBin)
    /// </summary>
    public string HostWebSite
    {
        get
        {
            string host = App.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri;
            int clientBin = host.IndexOf("ClientBin", 0);
            if (clientBin == -1)
                return "Could not find \"ClientBin\" in " + host;

            return host.Substring(0, clientBin);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I feel like this needs to throw an exception rather than return a spurious string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "http://www.abc.com/123/product/234?productid=123";
bool contains = myString.Contains("http://www.abc.com/123");
```

Comment: I want to write a generalize code !!! I hoped that is self-understod. It was just an example, please don't go by the values provided in example and think in general.

Comment: What if I try http://www.xyz.com/http://www.abc.com/123 ? that still passes the test!

Comment: What do you mean by generalizing it?

Comment: David, the string xyz.com/http://www.abc.com/123 does contain the URL http://www.abc.com/123, so it seems to me that it's correct.  Why do you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current uri using HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri (this works in *.xaml.cs files)